# How to use fieldsets without causing registry() error?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

New to django. I was trying to modify my model to get 2 fields on the same line. After reading documentation on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/
I tried the following in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *


# Register your models here.

class NewsAdd(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {
            'fields': ('field1'('field2','field3'),'field4','field5','field6','field7')})]

class NewsDisplay(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_display = ('nick','hosty','msg','info','specjalista','od','do') 
    search_fields = ('nick','hosty','msg','info','specjalista','od','do') 

admin.site.register(News, NewsDisplay, NewsAdd)
```

Please don't mind the News and NewsDisplay in admin.site.register as those work correctly.

As soon as I add NewsAdd to admin.site.register() I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000000044C5E18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 120, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ji34ix\PycharmProjects\Diego\src\Hosting\Wmit_news\admin.py", line 21, in <module>
    admin.site.register(News, NewsDisplay, NewsAdd)
TypeError: register() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I am sure that I'm missing something very simple here but can't solve it on my own. Cany anyone please help ?

Comment: What is `NewsDisplay`?

Comment: It modifies the model so all properties of created items are displayed. It sits in models.py. Code (can't format is a code in comments):                               class NewsDisplay(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nick','hosty','msg','info','specjalista','od','do')
    search_fields = ('nick','hosty','msg','info','specjalista','od','do')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supposed to be a single `ModelAdmin` class.

`admin.site.register` has two arguments: `Model` class and appropriate `ModelAdmin` class. You are trying to pass three arguments which is illegal.

[list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), [search_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) and [fieldsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) can be combined in a single class definition.

```
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {
            'fields': ('field1'('field2','field3'),'field4','field5','field6','field7')})]
    list_display = ('nick','hosty','msg','info','specjalista','od','do') 
    search_fields = ('nick','hosty','msg','info','specjalista','od','do') 

admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
```